# API Requests Failing for Some Users Despite Stable Internet Connection

Tags: android, spring-boot, kotlin, retrofit, network-connection

I have deployed a native Android app built in Kotlin and Retrofit to the Play Store, currently used by over 200k users. While the majority of users are experiencing no issues and the app works fine, I've received reports from some users indicating that API requests fail when using both WiFi and mobile data connections.

These users have confirmed having a stable internet connection, and the backend server, which is a Spring Boot application deployed on AWS, boasts high availability. However, the API requests from the affected users consistently fail.

I'm struggling to pinpoint the root cause of this issue. Could it be related to specific network configurations, device-specific settings, or any other factors that might affect API requests? I'd appreciate any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps to identify and resolve this issue.

Network Diagnostics: Our Android team have thoroughly checked and verified both the debug and release APK builds that they are making successful API requests and majority of the users have never complained about such an issue, this can also be verified through user Actions tracking by Amplitude.

Backend Server Status: Verified the status of the backend server (Spring Boot application on AWS) to ensure high availability and responsiveness.

Comment: Could have many potential causes, have you thought about adding logging / reporting for those `IOExceptions` that occur on the client side? Using a service like [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics) or something similar you could have them reported to you to gain some more data on this

Comment: Fatal Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
Caused by java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
There is this crash in Crashlytics for some users. Can it be related ?

Comment: you can fix this to increase your api client time request and response time  

or share your api client code so it's easy to find issue